# Forward every port depending on domain

Tags: ssh, ftp, port-forwarding

A friend and I are doing some little webhosting for us. Currently all the pages are running on one Server via Apache2's virtual hosts. Know we want to make single servers for each site with ssh-access, ftp server and some other stuff.

I tried around a little bit and found out ProxyPass like in the following example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.141/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.2.141/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

It seems to work pretty good but it only works for the http protocol. I also want it to forward ssh, ftp, etc.

Has somebody any idea?

Comment: Apache is an HTTP server. Don't expect it to handle SSHd and FTPd as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you are using *Name Based Virtual Hosting* which works because `apache` reads the HTTP header for the hostname of the client and decides which `<VirtualHost>` block to use depending on that value.  Your block tells it to proxy the request to another server.

There is no similar facility in `ssh` or `ftp`.

The nearest you can get is to use `iptables` to forward packets from a port to a different server:

```
# iptables - nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1022 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.141:22
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

This will listen on port 1022 of your server and forward traffic to port 22 of 192.168.2.141. You (or your friend) will then need to `ssh [username@]192.168.2.141 -p 1022` to access that server.

You can add another `iptables` line to transfer port 1023 to port 22 of another server, and so on. You could probably do the same with `ftp` by reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/252425/forward-ftp-with-iptables) ServerFault question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am thinking about something other so that I can use port 22

Comment: I'm afraid your *thinking* will have to progress to writing a SSH Reverse Proxy from scratch - good luck :-) Alternatively, you could log in to the outward facing server on port 22 and from there, `ssh` into your internal servers - not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: Nono, i do not want to do that. But let us say for a webhosting customer, it is not a very good way how to log into the server...

Comment: It certainly isn't. Unfortunately, that's all you've got as you'll only have one external facing IP address.

Comment: But then please tell me. How to webhosting services like amazon, godaddy or other providers handle this problem?

Comment: You either have an unique public IP address for every customer's server or you are on a shared hosting where many customers have an individual login on one server.  For example, 10 users share one server (Virtual Hosts for websites) and each one has a `ssh` and/or `ftp` login on that one server.  Service providers sometimes shy away from `ssh` access to shared servers as it could pose a security risk.

Comment: ok that seems clear to me. But what do I do, if there are a lot of customers and a lot of traffic to the sites?

Comment: The original question was not about (re)desigining hosting infrastructure, which is a different question and probably off-topic here.